# Issue with creating a symbolic link inside /System folder

Tags: mac, macos, root

I am trying to make a symbolic link inside the /System folder and even if I run the command as su I get the following error message.

```
macbook-pro:~ root# cd /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 
macbook-pro:5.12 root# ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/SVN/ SVN 
ln: SVN: Operation not permitted
macbook-pro:5.12 root# ls -ld /System
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root  wheel restricted 136 Sep 22 10:37 System
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: You need to disable SIP

Comment: I tried doing that by logging into Recovery mode and using terminal to run csrutil disable and I still have the same issue.

Comment: hmmm... I don't know what else to do. Where are you running the command from. What user account?

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff in the Apple Forum Post about this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3981 also I think there's an option to disable it from the Firmware Password tool in Recovery.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing you are doing this to get `git-svn` to work. I've tested this on `git 2.6.2`. If so, link to non restricted directory:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/SVN/ /Library/Perl/5.18/SVN
sudo mkdir /Library/Perl/5.18/auto
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/ /Library/Perl/5.18/auto/SVN
```

Comment: This worked for me to fix the error "Can't locate SVN/Core.pm" in SourceTree.